# "Member for 10 days" has posts created years ago

Tags: support, merge-accounts

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23512643/stats-noob) has a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73491512/how-to-create-a-dropdown-menu-in-flexdashboard) dated to Aug 25, 2022. But his profile says he's a member only for 10 days.

The image of the user's profile (at the time of this edit he's a member for 12 days):
[image: the image of the user's profile]

So what does the "member for..." date actually show? Or, why is that user only 10 days on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Could be the result of merging users?

Comment: Very likely a merge issue, guessing the *new* account was used as the target, rather than the old. They were [previously](https://web.archive.org/web/20240117023712/https://stackoverflow.com/users/13203841/stats-noob) a user for many years.

Comment: The merges happened in November 2023 though (source: mod tools). I don't see how the account could be 10 days old, but there's probably more merge weirdness that just didn't make it to the mod tools

Comment: There is a record consistent with a merger on 01.03.2024 (i.e. 10 days ago) where the rep inexplicably is recalculated from 1 to the 5k consistent with the previous vote update record in february. I have no clue what happened between those two timestamps, and there's no record of a merger like there normally would. I assume staff did something special, probably involving devs - might be an *un*merger? Those don't result in log entries IIRC, and result in the standard weird date mess expected from a merger.

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike re "unmerger" - potentially related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/398271/997587 ?

Comment: @starball I doubt it (there's not enough rep on SO in that pic), but if more accounts were involved, it's perfectly possible. I can't definitively confirm or deny though - I lack the data to do so

Comment: As long as the registration date is not in the future (the _member for_ statement does not indicate a _negative_ duration) everything is fine.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt, that's unless the member's name is John Connor.

Comment: Definitely a merge since the electorate badge, which that (new) user has earned, requires you be a member for 15 days, at minimum, based on the criteria (600 votes cast, with the system's maximum possible vote count per day of 40).

Comment: You often portray personal mistakes in your own choice of words. In my experience when you want to apply the word "weird" to something, that actually means you don't understand it. That should be the signal to resist any and all assumptions you will want to make. Like "bug". Ask a  "how" or "why" question instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that is not a bug.

It is a side-effect of [account merges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) and/or migrations. *[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376302)*

When two (or more) accounts get merged one of the accounts will be the target account. Today the oldest account would be used but that wasn't always the case. Merges happen either automatically when you login with a different account while you are already logged in, or by SE staff when you (or a moderator) requests to have profiles merged.

When a question is migrated to another site, it isn't required the OP has an account on the target site. Until they decide to create an account on the target site the post uses the ownerdisplayname. After they created the account their migrated posts are correctly associated with the user profile.

There are close to [three thousand](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1824328) profiles with posts prior their profile creation date.

I very much like what [Kai Burghardt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429424/weird-user-creation-date/429430#comment990414_429424) said in a comment and repeat it here for posterity:

> As long as the registration date is not in the future everything is fine.

Comment: Add: I've also seen a few accounts getting merged into an account that was not theirs the last few months. When this happens, you have to create a support ticket with SO/SE.

Comment: Uhm, it sounds very much like it IS a minor bug in the account merging procedures. The merged account can end up with a date that does not reflect the actual user age, and that probably shouldn't happen. It's not a big issue if it does happen, but I doubt it is intentional or wanted.

Comment: It's mildly unfair. A merge like this would prevent the user from getting the Yearling badges they earned.

Comment: eh, it'd be inaccurate/unfair if the account age was displayed *older* than it actually is due to posts migrated from elsewhere. The account is as old as the account is, older content being associated to it doesn't change that. You should only earn yearling badges for the years in which you had an account, not from some post that got migrated a few years earlier.